# Mac向けのアプリ開発でインストーラーを作成するためのツールはありますか？

Tags: macos

Windowsには[inno setup](http://inno-setup.sidefeed.com/)というインストーラーを作成するためのフリーソフトがあります。

Macでも、inno setupにあたるものを探しているのですが、良い感じのものが見つかりません。

[ここ](https://formac.informer.com/inno-setup)から、類似ソフトウェアを探して、Packagesというのを試してみたのですが操作方法が分からず、解説されているサイトもあまり見つかりません(Packagesという名前が一般名詞にもあるので、検索に引っかかりづらい)。Installer Makerという有料のソフトは、チュートリアルビデオが公開されているのですが、動画がFlashPlayerで作成されているせいか再生されません。

Macでインストーラーを作成するにはどのような方法、もしくはソフトウェアを使用すれば良いのでしょうか？
使用方法の解説があって使いやすいソフトウェアなどあれば教えて欲しいです。

Comment: https://qiita.com/ioue/items/9d1681286c50f8e7e98d は参考になりませんか？私も色々探した結果、無償で導入できるということで、この方法に落ち着いています。使いやすいかと言われると、ちょっと難しいかもしれません。コマンドラインで実行するものなので、*.shファイルにまとめてコマンド一つだけで実行、とすれば多少は楽になると思います。